# What is the interface of the proprietary memory card connector in CDTV

Tags: hardware, hardware-mods, amiga-cdtv

Is this an IDE or something completely different. Could it be used to connect gotek?

[image: CN13 CDTV Rev 2.2.1]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's [CN13](https://archive.org/details/CDTV_Service_Manual_1991-05_Commodore/page/n23/mode/1up). The pins are documented [here](http://www.hardwarebook.info/CDTV_Memory_Card) and have address and data lines as you would expect for memory, not the [signals](https://old.pinouts.ru/HD/InternalDisk_pinout.shtml) you would need for  a floppy drive.

I would connect a Gotek to the DB-23 connector on the rear panel.

Comment: Is there a way to connect it internally?

Comment: @BartekMalysz Short of soldering a ribbon cable to the pins of the DB-23, I don't see a way. But the DB-23 is already DF0, so if the purpose is to boot from floppy, you don't need to do anything internally.